# Second Order Recurrence Relation with Exogenous Forcing Sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am solving an infinite horizon maximization problem, which yields as FOC second-order recurrence relation

$A_{n+1} = \delta A_{n+2} + \delta A_{n} + c_n$,

where $\{c_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and $\delta$ are exogenous (i.e. I need a solution for $A_n$ in terms of $\delta$ and $c_n$). Is there a textbook way of solving this that I missed (no maths major here, so entirely possible)? (I know how to solve this without the forcing term).

Thanks and Best wishes,

Leon

Comment: Do you know anything about the forcing term? That would simplify the work to be done.

Comment: Sadly, no, I can see how that would make it easier(/possible?) (in the problem this is going to be an exogenous sequence of salary at time $t$)

Comment: Ok. Do you know the initial values of $A_n$ i.e. $A_0,A_1$?